# Can anyone tell me how to extract ShortformProvider for URI label annotations using Manchester Syntax used in protege

Tags: gwt, semantics, owl, protege

I am implementing a version that extracts the entity from URI of OWLEntity used in WebProtege. I am successful in that. I can show you the below code. But I require now to extract from label annotations. How do I extract it using WebProtege. WebProtege doesn't create the URI when creating a class (for e.g., http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/2005/05/16/pizza.owl#Pizza). it has only label annotation with URI. I would like to extract the URI from the label. As it has (for e.g., http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/2005/05/16/234y2890820802840> "Pizza"@en>. (Somewhat looking like this. I will reply if you need the correct one.).

```java
rootOntology = getProject().getRootOntology();
System.out.println(rootOntology.getAxioms());

final OWLDataFactory dataFactory 
  = rootOntology.getOWLOntologyManager().getOWLDataFactory();

iriShortFormProvider = new SimpleIRIShortFormProvider();
ShortFormProvider shortFormProvider = new ShortFormProvider() {

        public String getShortForm(OWLEntity owlEntity) {
                        return iriShortFormProvider.getShortForm(owlEntity.getIRI());
        }

        @Override
        public void dispose() {

        }
        };

OWLEntityChecker entityChecker 
  = new ShortFormEntityChecker(
      new BidirectionalShortFormProviderAdapter(
       Collections.singleton(rootOntology), shortFormProvider));

ManchesterOWLSyntaxEditorParser parser 
  = new ManchesterOWLSyntaxEditorParser(
      dataFactory, query);

parser.setOWLEntityChecker(entityChecker);

Set<OntologyAxiomPair> set;

try {
    set = parser.parseFrames();
    System.out.println("SET SIZE" + set.size());
    System.out.println("SET STRING" + set.toString());

    for (OntologyAxiomPair s1 : set) {

                OWLAxiom temp = s1.getAxiom();
                Set<OWLAnnotationProperty> annotation = s1.getOntology().getAnnotationPropertiesInSignature();
        Iterator itr = annotation.iterator();

                while(itr.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(s1.getOntology().getAnnotationPropertiesInSignature());
            System.out.println("ITERATOR" + itr.next());
                }

                if (temp.getAxiomType() != AxiomType.DECLARATION
                        || temp.getAxiomType() != AxiomType.SUBCLASS_OF || temp.getAxiomType() != AxiomType.DATA_PROPERTY_ASSERTION 
                        )
            res = Search(temp);             
    }
```

Example coming from WebProtege:

```xml
<!-- http://webprotege.stanford.edu/classes/BfJkwFDiEj5mduXojVHyKi -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="http://webprotege.stanford.edu/classes/BfJkwFDiEj5mduXojVHyKi">
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">AnimalType</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing"/>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://webprotege.stanford.edu/classes/BjSxQcpX7bOcVccVf5beN0 -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="http://webprotege.stanford.edu/classes/BjSxQcpX7bOcVccVf5beN0">
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">Omnivore</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://webprotege.stanford.edu/classes/BfJkwFDiEj5mduXojVHyKi"/>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://webprotege.stanford.edu/classes/CKjBW7KqdcJPRpBtk2T6WE -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="http://webprotege.stanford.edu/classes/CKjBW7KqdcJPRpBtk2T6WE">
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">Herbivore</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://webprotege.stanford.edu/classes/BfJkwFDiEj5mduXojVHyKi"/>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://webprotege.stanford.edu/classes/COt181AeQ0WewmOoZ0NYYF -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="http://webprotege.stanford.edu/classes/COt181AeQ0WewmOoZ0NYYF">
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">Fish</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://webprotege.stanford.edu/classes/DfGxuPUoLBiOvyBKpUJWvr"/>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://webprotege.stanford.edu/classes/CPp9DIflV676wmq3onRsJa -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="http://webprotege.stanford.edu/classes/CPp9DIflV676wmq3onRsJa">
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">Land</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://webprotege.stanford.edu/classes/7V0PYXjh6vM9AjTzh9DPwC"/>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://webprotege.stanford.edu/classes/DfGxuPUoLBiOvyBKpUJWvr -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="http://webprotege.stanford.edu/classes/DfGxuPUoLBiOvyBKpUJWvr">
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">Animal</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing"/>
</owl:Class>
```

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that WebProtege doesn't allow you to specify the URIs of the classes and individuals that you create?  Update:  I just played with WebProtege, and it does seem that way.  This is _very_ surprising to me;  an OWL tool in which you can't specify URIs is not very useful.  I hope that we're just missing something here.

Comment: @Joshua, yes, that's right. we can't get the full URI.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get your labels. Although it is true that URIs are preferable, but labels are also workable. You can feed these labels to your Manchester Syntax query. I would suggest rewriting your query.

```
OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
    File file= new File("root-ontology.owl");

    OWLOntology rootOntology = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(file);

    OWLDataFactory df  = rootOntology.getOWLOntologyManager().getOWLDataFactory();

    Set<OWLLogicalAxiom> LogicalAxiom=rootOntology.getLogicalAxioms();
    Iterator<OWLLogicalAxiom> axiom=LogicalAxiom.iterator();


        for (OWLClass cls : rootOntology.getClassesInSignature()) {

            // Get the annotations on the class that use the label property
            for (OWLAnnotation annotation : cls
                    .getAnnotations(rootOntology, df.getRDFSLabel())) {
                if (annotation.getValue() instanceof OWLLiteral) {
                    OWLLiteral val = (OWLLiteral) annotation.getValue();
                    // look for portuguese labels
                    if (val.hasLang("en"))
                        System.out.println( val.getLiteral());
                }
            }
        }
```